# What is wrong with this regex match in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am having issues with matching this particular regex in python, can someone see what is wrong?

Sample strings I am trying to match with a single regular expression are:

```
string = '[Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: 5.50 MP]'
string = '[Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: 1.2 MP]'
string = '[Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: 0.5 MP]'
string = '[Post-Avatar Mode: 0 MP]'
```

I have tried the following, but there doesnt seem to be a single expression that matches all of them:

```
m = re.match('\[.*(?P<cost>\d+(\.\d+)).*\]', string) # Appears to match only ones with #.#
m = re.match('\[.*(?P<cost>\d+(\.\d+)?).*\]', string) # Appears to match the 0 only, unable to print out m.groups for the others
```

I am trying to catch (5.50, 1.2, 0.5, 0, etc.)

Comment: which part of the string you're trying to match?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example, like `string = "[Pre-Avatar Mode Cost: 5.50 MP]"`, and `m = re.match('[.*(?P<cost>\d+(\.\d+)).*\]', string)`

Comment: Seems like you're missing the `:` and whitespaces.

Comment: I am trying to catch the Numerical Part.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Updated original post.

Comment: Did you ever get around to trying my answer to your previous question on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the first `.*` match non-greedy (add a `?`), it'll swallow the numbers otherwise:

```
r'\[.*?(?P<cost>\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*\]'
```

I've also made the optional `.number` part a non-capturing group to simplify processing the output:

```
>>> import re
>>> costre = re.compile(r'\[.*?(?P<cost>\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*\]')
>>> costre.match('[Post-Avatar Mode: 0 MP]').groups()
('0',)
>>> costre.match('[Post-Avatar Mode: 5.50 MP]').groups()
('5.50',)
>>> costre.match('[Post-Avatar Mode: 1.2 MP]').groups()
('1.2',)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the `:` as the anchor. That way, you get a more robust expression:

```
r'\[.*: (?P<cost>\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*\]'
```

You might even want to add on the `MP` suffix if it's guaranteed to be in the text.